# Hide a field from a django ModelForm depending on user's profile

Tags: python, django

I have a form that has two fields (mail and status). I want to have the status field hidden only when the user has a profile not equal to "tech" so that the user cannot change its value in that case.

What I was trying to do, but I still didn't get it to work since it throws me `TypeError error: __init __ () got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`, is to overwrite the `__init __ ()` method of RequestForm in forms.py and on the other hand, overwrite the `get_form_kwargs ()` method to pass the user to the form. I post the code that I understand relevant:

**views.py:**

```
...
class RequestUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Request
    form_class = RequestForm
    template_name = 'request/request_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('request:request_list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

**forms.py:**

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = [
            'mail',
            'status',
        ]
        labels = {
            'mail': 'E-Mail (including @domain.example)',
            'status': "Request's status:"
        }
        widgets = {
            'mail': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.user.is_tech == False:
            self.fields.pop('status')
```

**models.py**

```
...
class Request(models.Model):
   mail = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   states = [('1','Pending'), ('2','In process'), ('3','Done')]
   status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=states, default='1')
   user = models.ManyToManyField(Requester, blank=True)
```

Why does the `* unexpected keyword argument 'user' *` error occur? What suggestions could you make to hide that field according to the user's profile?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to only override get_form method as follow in RequestUpdate:

```
def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(self.form_class)
    if not self.request.user.status.is_tech:
        form.fields.pop('status')
    return form
```

I don't know why your code fails, but anyway you can tweak your form in view class so no need to do more work.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly,(there is a minimal error on if's condition as status is not part of the user).